# Bitmap size exceed exception occur when fetching image form Internet

Tags: android, image, exception

I have a problem in fetching image form internet the problem is that.
I have a listview with custom layout image view and textview.
 In my case i am fetching image form internet using the given blow function but when a large image come the **Bitmap size exception occur**.

```
    private static InputStream fetch(String urlString)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        return response.getEntity().getContent();
    }

    Resources res;

    // *********** Function For Fetching Image form Internet
    public static Drawable LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {

        try {

            if (fetch(URL) != null) {
                try {
                    InputStream obj = fetch(URL);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(obj, null, options);
                    obj.reset();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
                return drawable;
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        TennisAppActivity.mContext.getResources(),
                        R.drawable.profileplaceholder);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                return drawable;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("GUIMethodClasas", "fetchDrawable failed", e);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I am using the above code for fetching image from internet.
Please any buddy give me a solution ASAP.

Comment: please define a "large image". Size? Dimension? Stacktrace?

Comment: This works with some images I'm assuming but only crashes with large ones? I have some similar code with image resizing to prevent a similar error when selecting large images from the gallery which I'll post when I get in from work.

Answer (score 0):

Use BitmapFactory options and set a higher sampling size than default, in order to consume less memory and get a smaller image, easier to handle by your application.

You can do so like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; //or any number you like. A power of 2 is recommended.
```

Then you can pass those options to your function, so that they are used when you decode the stream.

The blur you mention is the cost of downsampling an image. If you don't reduce the number of samples, you won't be able to reduce it's size when you are getting it from the stream.

Comment: I have given the value for BitmapFactory.Options=5 then problem is solve but image is bluer. But i want to image without bluer.

Comment: I posted a code example with the appropriate way to use BitmapFactory options, and explaining the blur is a consequence of downsampling.